# Passing regex expression via API results in an error

Tags: javascript, regex, express, nedb

I have created an API using Express in NodeJS which is using NeDB for its database.

I have examined the documentation and I can see that there is a way to filter results using regular expressions in order to carry out operations similar to "like" in SQL.

I am able to get the regular expressions to work when creating a hardcoded JSON object to use as the filter but when a filter is passed via my API, NeDB reports the following error:

`Error: $regex operator called with non regular expression`

My test database contains the following documents:

```
[
    {
        "test": "Hello",
        "other": "Goodbye",
        "_id": "9T0WaZ240q6ZK747"
    },
    {
        "test": "sup!",
        "other": "Ta ta",
        "extra": "something",
        "_id": "jLUzEZjLDVX1lmU5"
    }
]
```

When I execute a `find()` on the data using a hardcoded JSON filter it will return the correct result e.g.

```
{
     test: {
         $regex: /hell/i
     }
}
```

will return the first record in the database.

However, when I call the `find()` function from my API where I am passing the JSON object filter across, I receive the error mentioned before.

The filter from my API gets added as follows:

`{ test: { '$regex': '/hell/i' } }`

It looks like it may be the single quotes that are causing some issues but even after stripping them out it does not work. Either I get the same error or some other JSON parsing error.

I examined the code for NeDB and in the `model.js` file I added a line to print to the console what regular expression it had detected. In both cases (the hardcoded method that worked and the API method) the regular expression was returned as:

`/hell/i`

So it seems that NeDB is receiving an identical expression for both calls but for some reason throws an error with the API method.

Has anyone tried passing a JSON filter to an NeDB instance using the `find()` method and have it filter successfully?

I am using Postman for my API testing.

Comment: JSON has no regex type.

Comment: That's true, I understand that. Is there no way I can pass something to NeDB so that it is interpreted as one?

Comment: Use a string `'hell'` and then build a regex using `new RegExp($regex, 'i')`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. That is an option for me, however, I wanted to make the API as flexible as possible so people could define their own regex and it would be interpreted by NeDB without extra work for me to format and build it before passing it along to NeDB

Comment: User-defined regexps are built using `new RegExp` constructor, there is no other way in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, due to you pointing me towards the `new RegExp` function steered me towards my sort-of solution I posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now managed to work out a sort-of solution. This is by no means perfect and still requires some more work and testing.

I ended up modifying the `model.js` file within NeDB, more specifically the `comparisonFunctions.$regex` function. I added an additional check to see if the regular expression that gets passed in can be converted to a regular expression from its string form. The `model.js` file now looks as follows:

```
comparisonFunctions.$regex = function (a, b) {

  if (!util.isRegExp(b)) {

    try {

      // convert the string based regex into an actual regular expression
      b = new RegExp(b.replace(/[\\/]/g, ""), 'i');

      // check again if it worked
      if (!util.isRegExp(b))
        throw new Error("$regex operator called with non regular expression");

    } catch {

      // we were not working with a regex
      throw new Error("$regex operator called with non regular expression");

    }
  }

  if (typeof a !== 'string') {
    return false
  } else {
    return b.test(a);
  }
};
```

So now if I pass this to my API:

```
{
    "test": {
        "$regex": "/ell/"
    }
}
```

It will return the first document from the database where the `test` field == `Hello`

Any recommendations on how to make this neater and/or feedback will be greatly appreciated.